# How to use Standalone Components, Pipes, or Directives in feature modules

Tags: angular, angular14, angular-standalone-components

I updated my angular project to angular **14**. Now I want to have some `standalone components`, `pipes`, or `directives`.

I have a featured module named **ProductModule** and want to use a standalone pipe called **uppercase** in this module.

```
// structure
---Product
          ---product.component
          ---product.service
          ---product.module.ts

---StandabloneFolder
                    ---uppercase.pipe.ts
```

My uppercase pipe

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'uppercase',
    standalone: true,
})
export class UppercasePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {
        return "UPPERCASE_INPUT"
    }
}
```

in product.component.html

```
{{'Javascript Addicted' |uppercase}}
```

get the following error:

> No pipe found with name 'uppercase' product.component.ts(6, 39): Error
> occurs in the template of component ProductComponent.

**NOTE:**

This problem will be solved if I add `standalone: true` to the **product.component** and remove the **ProductComponent** from **declarations array**.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to add the UppercasePipe to the `imports` of *product.module.ts*.

**product.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [/*some import*/, UppercasePipe],
  /* other stuff*/
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

Comment: I'm talking about standalone pipes , more information https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components

Comment: So do I. In order to make the pipe for Products available, you need to import it in the product's module.

Comment: I know, It's your right, but I want to do that with ``standalone`` feature

Comment: I believe you are confused. UppercasePipe is standalone, when imported (like my example). If UppercasePipe is not standalone, then you would need to add it to a declarations array.

Comment: It's your right. you saved my day. thanks for spending your valuable time answering my questions

Comment: @AbolfazlRoshanzamir, if your ProductComponent is standalone, you should not have any ProductModule anymore and declare your standalone pipe in the import option of your ProductComponent. Standalone pipes still need to be declared in imports.

Comment: In standalone mode https://stackoverflow.com/a/77107538/2816916 should be the acceped answer, not this.

Answer (score 5):

you only need import it in your imports section component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './basic-page.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  styles: [],
  imports: [JsonPipe],
})
export class BasicPageComponent {}
```

Template HTML:

```
<pre>{{ "objeto" | json }}</pre>
```

Comment: what if JsonPipe use a service?

Comment: Hi, Import it...

Answer (score 0):

if you want your pipe to be standalone, you can make the standalone attribute true.
ex:

```
@Pipe({  
   name: 'my_pipe_name',  
   standalone: true,
})
```

*Note: I have used this with angular 17, I don't know if it is the same with angular 14*

Answer (score 0):

if the intention is for everything to be standalone the pipe must also be standalone

```
@Pipe({  
     name: 'pipe',  
     standalone: true,
});
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    standalone:true,
    imports:[pipe]
});
```